# SQL database queries basic question AVG Difference

Tags: sql, average

I have a really basic question on SQL.

Relational Schema:

- Student (Sid, Sname )
- Class (Sid, ClassName, mark)
- ClassName = { MATH, ENGLISH, PHY, .......}

I want to list out all the student who have taken MATH, and their MATH class average minus the student's math mark

```
Select DINSTINCT S.Sname, (E.Mark - AVG (E.Mark))   
From Student As S, Class As C   
Where C.ClassName = 'MATH'  AND S.Sid = C.Sid
```

I don't know how to do difference; I don't think this is right; can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: How does a student get more than one mark in MATH?  Are you really looking for the difference between the student's average mark across all subjects and the mark they got in MATH?

Comment: @Jonathan, It looks as the consensus will be that there is illogical and therefore superfluous 'their' in the requirements...

Comment: Oh no I meant to say that there is a list of students, who took different subjects (math, english etc). And now I want to find out the average mark in the MATH class, then list out all the math student's name and their math mark minus (MATH class avg)

Comment: Well, I'll give +1 for first sentence of the question :)

Comment: lol i know i know.. i just started learning>.>

Comment: This sems very much like a homework question...  If it is, it's more polite to say so when asking.  You you be interested in Why as well as How if you have any intention of learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select DISTINCT S.Sname, E.Mark - (SELECT AVG(E.Mark)
                                     FROM Student
                                    WHERE C.ClassName = 'MATH')
From Student As S, Class As C   
Where C.ClassName = 'MATH'  AND S.Sid = C.Sid
```